Implementing Algolia search queries for product search by brand, name, variant, rating, price, stock, and discounts?
I'm using Algolia to create a product search feature on my ecommerce website. I have product data in JSON array format as shown below:
[{
  "id": 1688,
  "product_detail_id": 2420,
  "name": "BSN AMINO x",
  "brand": "BSN",
  "price": 770000,
  "sku": "530556",
  "variant": "Watermelon 435 gr Exp Date 1-25",
  "slug": "watermelon",
  "stock": 50,
  "image": "https://naturalfarm.sgp1.digitaloceanspaces.com/uploads/products/bsn-amino-x-watermelon-435-gr-exp-date-0524-6535e09243374.jpeg",
  "created_at": "2022-11-11 17:00:55",
  "variant_type": 3,
  "sold_qty": 17,
  "price_disc": 445000,
  "price_disc_vip": 0,
  "price_after_disc": 325000,
  "price_after_disc_vip": 0,
  "badge": "https://naturalfarm.sgp1.digitaloceanspaces.com/uploads/badge/sale.svg",
  "is_member": 0,
  "is_discount": 2,
  "start_date": "2024-04-03",
  "end_date": "2024-04-30",
  "promo_id": 23825,
  "promo_detail_id": 738786,
  "wishlist_status": 0,
  "promo_additional_item": [],
  "rating": 5,
  "rating_float": "5.0"
}]

I want to perform several search query scenarios for products using Algolia:

Search products by brand.
Search products by name and variant.
Search products by rating.
Search products by minimum price.
Search products by maximum price.
Search products by stock availability.
Search products by products that are currently on sale.
Search products by products that are currently on sale with a
specific discount percentage.
Search products by products that are currently on sale with a
specific discounted price.

How can I perform queries for the above scenarios using Algolia?

In algolia you can configure through the dashboard or the API "searchable attributes" (searchableAttributes) when you do a query it will use those attributes.
https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/managing-results/must-do/searchable-attributes/
Additionally you can filters and "numeric attributes for filtering" (numericAttributesForFiltering) so you can add filters like: price:10 TO 20
https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/managing-results/refine-results/filtering/
